# How to use double variables?

Tags: c#, .net

I need to adjust the value of a double variable. In order to do that I've written this extension method

```
public static class Helper
{
    public static double Adjust(this double value, double l, double h)
    {
        while (value < l)
            value += h;
        while (value >= h)
            value -= h;

        return value;
    }
}
```

But it doesn't give me the expected result.

Here I am calling my code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    double a = 10.1;
    Text = a.Adjust(5,10).ToString();
}
```

I was expecting the result to be `0.1`  but is  `0.099999999999999646`. I have figured out that it have something to do with the precision of the `double`  datatype. But how can I get my result to be 0.1?

Comment: Use _decimal_ for this operation.

Comment: Are you ***sure*** that *double* is a more appropriate datatype than, for example, *decimal(18,2)* or *decimal(18,4)*? Appropriate selection of datatype is part of what distinguishes senior developers from intermediates and juniors. Generally the *double* and *single* datatypes are only appropriate for scientific, engineering, and economic analysis; not routine accounting.

Comment: Worth to read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618535/difference-between-decimal-float-and-double-in-net?lq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, the double datatype isn't exact for mathematical operations.

Try using an exact decimal datatype like System.Decimal

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.aspx

Answer (score 2):

The result occurs due to [rounding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Floating-point_rounding) numbers represented in the `float` or `double` data type. The reason for the unexprected behaviour is the fact that not every rational number can be represented within a specific floating point type and the 'resolution' of representable numbers decreases with increasing absolute value.